# Updating a String Column with null value(Hibernate)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I have a input post-xml which is like below,

```
<Comment>
  <Comment1>Hello</Comment1>
  <Comment2>How Are You?</Comment2> 
</Comment>
```

Where "Comment2" is optional. If it is not present like below,

```
<Comment>
  <Comment1>Hello</Comment1>
</Comment>
```

I have to update the corresponding column value to null in table. I use MSSQL Server 2008. When doing this using Hibernate i tried like below;

```
if(commentPostXml.getComment2() != null){
  commentsTablePojo.setComment2(commentPostXml.getComment2());
}else{
  commentsTablePojo.setComment2(null);
}
```

and also tried completely removing the else part. But it never updates the column to null value, instead it just keeps the previous value. In DB that column is null value allowed column. Please tell me how can i update the value with null.

Comment: Can you add Pojo code of Comment

Comment: Hi I found how to do it. If i take a String with a null value and then set the string there it is working, but if i set a null directly it does not work. Strange, i dont understand what is the difference..